# Can I use instagram's api for an ios app as an image bank by sending gps location

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, coordinates, instagram

I'd like to know if I can use Instagram's api for retrieving images to an ios application.

I'd like to get the images according to a gps location that will be sent to the server.

Is it doable? Is it ok by the privacy policy? Should I add any credit to the image while presenting it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is in fact they have an API that will even assist you with retrieving GPS coordinates for photos.

http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

You have to register as a developer and have to abide their terms and conditions (in regards to the number of requests that can be made per second and user login etc)

It is doable ( I am doing it right now!!)

In regards to presenting the images - this is probably not the right forum to ask that question - you should contact a lawyer. Good luck!